# case when using multiple conditions across multiple columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

So quick example:

[image]

I need to change that 'imperial' to 'Metric' in the UnitsofMeterRemoved Column. However it has to be when meter model = g4 and MeterManufacturerRemoved = KROMSCHRODER.

I have tried this

```
SELECT *,
CASE WHEN MeterModelRemoved = 'G4'
    AND MeterManufacturerRemoved = 'KROMSCHRODER'
    AND UnitsofMeterRemoved = 'Imperial'
    THEN UnitsofMeterRemoved = 'Metric'
    END AS MeterModelRemoved
FROM CTE_2
```

But the Imperial is still showing up? Any ideas why this may be happening?

Comment: do you want to create a new column or update an existing one?

Comment: Hi Aleix, i tried that but still getting 'Imperial' coming back!

Comment: Update an existing one, i want to replace the imperial with metric with the above criteria

Comment: So UnitsofMeterRemoved returns with metric instead of Imperial once all the conditions have been met. Or is this not the best way to do that?

Comment: Do you mean `THEN 'Metric'`?

Comment: THEN 'Metric'
    END AS UnitsofMeterRemoved

still returns the imperial string in UnitsofMeterRemoved

Comment: You select all columns as they are, so you will select also `'imperical'`, the case expression will return `'metric'`. The case expression will also need an `ELSE`, by the way

Comment: This is still returning the Imperial string? im not sure whats going on. Could it be the CTE?

Comment: @MizanurChoudhury please share the cte code, and a sample of the original data (as (formatted) text, ideally as a create statement for the table(s) and inserts for the data, absolutely **not** as picture)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use below

```
SELECT * EXCEPT(UnitsofMeterRemoved),
  CASE WHEN MeterModelRemoved = 'G4'
    AND MeterManufacturerRemoved = 'KROMSCHRODER'
    AND UnitsofMeterRemoved = 'Imperial'
  THEN 'Metric'
  ELSE UnitsofMeterRemoved
  END AS UnitsofMeterRemoved
FROM CTE_2
```